# Wordpress Password Protect Archive and Single Posts for Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, custom-post-type

Is there an easy way to password protect an archive and single posts of a custom post type?

I found this article on password protecting single posts, but am still lost on the archive loop. I would want it only display the password box until the user has logged in.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/forcing-all-posts-associated-with-a-custom-post-type-to-be-private

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For single pages you could just edit `single.php` and add something along the lines of:

```
<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  // Show Post to Logged in User
} 
else {
  //Show password field
}

?>
```

If like you mentioned you are using a custom post type or an archive template you could apply the same method as above to `single-[custom-post-type-name].php` or `archive.php`

Answer (score 7):

The only way I've found to quickly password-protect the archive is by creating a template that retrieves the custom post type data and associating it with a page that can be password protected.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Once that page is password protected, you find the post ID to apply it to the single-{your_custom_post_type}.php like so:

```
<?php
if ( !post_password_required('{protected_post_id}') ) : ?>

//protected content here

<?php else:
    //show the password form of the protected page
    echo get_the_password_form('{protected_post_id}');                 

endif; ?>
```

This saves you from having to password-protect every post under your custom post type.